# Are the vectors linearly independent? If they are dependent, find numbers that make the equation true.

Tags: linear-algebra

*Note: I already know they're dependent. However, I cannot solve this problem. I have already done a very similar problem like this, but cannot figure out this specific example.

I have the following vectors:

$6x-15+15x^2$

$6-12x-3x^2$

$11+2x-13x^2$

I then had to solve the equation once I knew that they were dependent.

$0=a(6x-15+15x^2)+b(6-12x-3x^2)+c(11+2x-13x^2)$

I distributed the a, b, and c and then I separated them into powers of x: $15a+6b+11c=0, 6a-12b+2c=0, 15a-3b-13c=0$. Once I started solving I got: $b=(15a+11c/6)$, $a=c$,$0=0$. Once I had gotten that a=c, I got b=$2c/3$. I then got a=0,b=0,c=0 which is not correct according to my webwork.

It says that I cannot have all of the numbers equal to zero if it is dependent. Any help is appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: $b=(15a+11c)/-6$

Comment: Try a nonzero value for $c$.  If $a=c, b=2c/3$ is correct (I haven't checked) then $a=b=c=0$ is a solution, but so is $a=c=2, b=2,$ and infinitely many others.

Comment: @saulspatz I didn't realize that I could just plug a number in for c. I was just thinking that it had to be whatever I got. Thank you.

Comment: When you solve a system of linear equations, you'll find that it either has no solutions, or exactly one solution, in which case each variable must be some fixed number, or it has infinitely many solutions in which case, certain of the variables are expressed in terms of the others.  When this happens, you can assign whatever values you like to the independent variables (the "others"), and solve for the dependent ones.